# SQLite Windows Phone character encoding not working

Tags: c#, sqlite, encoding, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 app with an SQLite database to store localized strings. I use the SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 extension for this, and I'm programming in C#. However, when I store the localized strings in the database, special characters like 'å', 'ö' etc. appear as '�' in the SQLite database.

I already tried the following:

1) convert the C# strings to UTF-8, UTF-16 or Unicode before storing them in the database, with no help. It appears that encoding strings in C# is useless.

2) set the SQLite database to use UTF-16 encoding with PRAGMA encoding="UTF-16"; when creating the database. The pragma is correctly processed, but the special characters are still '�'.

My assumption is that there is something going wrong in the C++ code of the SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 extension.

Storing the localized strings elsewhere is not an option, so how can I get the SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 extension to store the special characters correctly?

C# code:

```
public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>> ExecuteQuery(string query)
{
    lock (LockObject)
    {
        var sqCommand = new SQLiteCommand(_sqLiteConnection) { CommandText = query };
        return sqCommand.ExecuteQueryEx();
    }
}
```

and the query executed is:

```
INSERT INTO LocalizedStrings (Id, LocalizedKey_Id, Language_Id, StringValue) VALUES (13,13,1053,'Sökområde');
```

And the SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQueryEx code:

```
public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>> ExecuteQueryEx()
{
    if (_conn.Trace)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Executing Query: " + this);
    }
    var result = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();
    var stmt = Prepare();

    while (SQLite3.Step(stmt) == SQLite3.Result.Row)
    {
        var columnCount = SQLite3.ColumnCount(stmt);
        var row = new Dictionary<string,object>();

        for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            var columnName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(SQLite3.ColumnName(stmt, i));
            var columnType = SQLite3.ColumnType(stmt, i);
            var value = ReadColEx(stmt, i, columnType);
            row.Add(columnName, value);
        }
        result.Add(row);
    }

    Finalize(stmt);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Share your code for better answers and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this problem can be solved using this solution:
[bug report at github](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/147)

Using this technique, I added a partial SQLiteCommand Class with a special Prepare2 method to convert the CommandText string into a UTF8 byte array:

```
[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_prepare_v2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern SQLite3.Result Prepare2(IntPtr db, byte[] queryBytes, int numBytes, out IntPtr stmt, IntPtr pzTail);

private Sqlite3Statement Prepare2()
{
    IntPtr statement;
    var queryBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CommandText);
    var result = Prepare2(_conn.Handle, queryBytes, queryBytes.Length, out statement, IntPtr.Zero);

    if (result != SQLite3.Result.OK)
    {
        throw SQLiteException.New(result, SQLite3.GetErrmsg(_conn.Handle));
    }

    BindAll(statement);
    return statement;
}
```

The 'Prepare()' method in the question code example is replaced by this new 'Prepare2()' method, and now, the special characters correctly appear in the SQLite database.